# Phonegap captureAudio in Android - recording format

Tags: android, cordova

When I use the PhoneGap's captureAudio API, the recording is stored on Android phone as a .3ga file. Can I store this recording as a AMR format instead? I'm trying to pass this recording into a voice recognition http api and the api expects AMR formatting.

From the [PhoneGap's documents](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio),
the Android the recording is encoded using AMR format, but I see the files created as .3ga files. Any suggestions on how to record in AMR format